# Setting Drawer Title in 2 Languages (Through Code?)

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_homepage"
            android:icon="@drawable/homemenu"
            android:title="@string/home" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

How do I set title Home in two languages? I created another folder values-in, and made one strings.xml, but it's not working. Is there any other way on how to use the title through coding?

Comment: Hi, adding new `values-xxx`will work if you change your phone language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create resources directory (values/drawable/layout/menu/anim) for our local language also like:

- -kn //Kannada
- -te //Telugu
- -ta //Tamil
- -hi //Hindi
- -en //default for english

now you can create a value directory for tamil 'values-ta'
Create ‘string.xml’ and and write your tamil label in it

```
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = locale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```

Answer (score 1):

using *string.xml* is the good approach for supporting multiple languages. Take a look at this [tutotial](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-building-multi-language-supported-app/).

But however you can achieve the same with the code & this is how it will look like.

```
if(language.equals("tamil")) {
    navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setTitle("இந்தியா");
} else {
    navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setTitle("india");
}
```